# 'No implementation for Kind' when Kind is a PolyModel child

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a model with properties:

```
_foo = db.ListProperty(db.Key)
@property 
def foo(self):
    return [db.get(f) for f in self._foo]
```

`_foo` is list of `Bar` keys, where:

```
class Barbie(polymodel.PolyModel):
    #...

class Bar(Barbie):
    #...
```

However, when `get()` in `foo` is called, I get a:

> KindError: No implementation for kind 'Bar'

[Every other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781435/no-implementation-for-kind-exception-python-google-app-engine) I've found on this has been answered by "you need to import the model for that kind".

Well, I have. To sanity check, I changed `db.get` to `Bar.get` and got the same error. If I then remove my import, obviously I get 'global name Bar is not defined', so it is picking up that import okay.

Those other questions weren't about PolyModels though, so I tried changing my `Bar` and sibling model to `db.Model`s, with duplicate properties rather than derivations of a `PolyModel`. Then, it worked immediately.

To check I hadn't changed anything else, I reverted to the `PolyModel`, and it immediately broke with the same `KindError`.

Why is this `get` not working with a `PolyModel` class, but fine with a `db.Model` class - according to [the docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/polymodelclass#PolyModel_class_key), `PolyModel` only adds to the available methods.

Comment: It works when I do that. Maybe your actual code isn't doing exactly what you've described?

Comment: Hmm. I didn't mention that `_foo` is a list of `Bar`s and `Barn`s, where both are derived from `Barbie`. But it fails on the first (a `Bar`, which is what I checked with `Bar.get`)